# Proof: $A=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_n\}\subset \Bbb{R} \to A \mbox{ is bounded above }$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I must proof the following:

***Prop.:*** Let be $\Bbb{R}$ a complete ordered field $$A=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_n\}\subset \Bbb{R} \to A \mbox{ is bounded above }$$
***Proof.:*** by induction on $n$, with $n \geq 1$ therefore

**1**. $n=1$, I have $A=\{c_1\}$, and $c_1 \in M(A) \wedge c_1 \in A$ therefore $c_1 \doteq \max(A)$

**2**. $n\to n+1$, I must proof $$[A=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_n\}\subset \Bbb{R} \to A \mbox{ is bounded above }]\to$$$$\to [A=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_n,c_{n+1}\}\subset \Bbb{R} \to A \mbox{ is bounded above }]$$ I consider $\{c_1,c_2,...,c_n,c_{n+1}\}=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_n\} \cup \{c_{n+1}\}$ and by hypothesis $A=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_n\}\subset \Bbb{R}$ is bounded above therefore $\exists r (r \doteq \sup(A))$, and $c_{n+1}\doteq \sup(\{c_{n+1}\}=\max(\{c_{n+1}\})$... by trichotomy: $$\mbox{ or } r=c_{n+1} \mbox{ or } r < c_{n+1} \mbox{ or } r > c_{n+1}$$ therefore:

$r=c_{n+1}$, then $\forall x \in \{c_1,c_2,..,c_n,c_{n+1}\}(x \leq r=c_{n+1})$, in fact by $\{c_1,c_2,..,c_n,c_{n+1}\}=\{c_1,c_2,..,c_n\} \cup \{c_{n+1}\}$ if $x \in \{c_1,c_2,..,c_n\} $ then $x\leq r$ is true by hypothesis; if $x \in \{c_{n+1}\}$ then $x=c_{n+1} \leq r=c_{n+1}$ is true because $\leq$ is reflexive relation

$r < c_{n+1}$, by Archimedean property $\exists n \in \Bbb{Z}( c_{n+1}<n)$.. therefore $r<c_{n+1}<n$, then $\forall x \in \{c_1,c_2,..,c_n,c_{n+1}\}(x \leq n)$, in fact by $\{c_1,c_2,..,c_n,c_{n+1}\}=\{c_1,c_2,..,c_n\} \cup \{c_{n+1}\}$ if $x \in \{c_1,c_2,..,c_n\}$ then $x \leq r < c_{n+1}< n \to x \leq n \wedge x \neq n$; ife $x \in \{c_{n+1}\}$ then $x=c_{n+1} \leq n \wedge x \neq n$ by Archimedean property

$r > c_{n+1}$, by Archimedean property $\exists m \in \Bbb{Z}( r<m)$.. therefore $m>r>c_{n+1}$, then $\forall x \in \{c_1,c_2,..,c_n,c_{n+1}\}(x \leq m)$, in fact by $\{c_1,c_2,..,c_n,c_{n+1}\}=\{c_1,c_2,..,c_n\} \cup \{c_{n+1}\}$ if $x \in \{c_1,c_2,..,c_n\}$ then $m>r\geq x  \to m\geq x \wedge m \neq x$; if $x \in \{c_{n+1}\}$ then $m>r>x=c_{n+1}$ therefore $m \geq x \wedge m \neq x $ by Archimedean property

It is correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is thorough and correct, though it could easily be made more general.

The statement is true for any totally ordered set, as you can make this proof without using the existence of a supremum (any upper bound will do) and without the use of the archimedean property. Just use the largest of r and $c_{n+1}$ as an upper bound.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my solution? I am just getting started at stack exchange and i would like to build up my reputation :)